# VBA Module doesn't seem to connect to the sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have been working on debugging this code and I am running into an issue where the code runs fine (no errors) but the changes it is supposed to be making aren't happening in the actual sheet.

## What the code is supposed to do:

The goal is to be able to check on saving if any cells have been changed. If they have, it locks all cells with non-blank values and protects the sheet to avoid having those cells edited in future instances.

## Here is the code itself:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sMSG As String

    sMSG = "Saving the workbook will lock the cells you have entered data into." & vbLf
    sMSG = sMSG & "Do you want to go ahead?"
    If Not bRangeEdited Then GoTo Xit
    If Not Me.ReadOnly Then
        Sheet1.Unprotect "password"
        With Sheet1.Range("A1:I20")
            If MsgBox(sMSG, vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
                GoTo Xit
            End If

            If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address <> .Address Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Locked = True
                bRangeEdited = False
            End If
        
        End With
        Sheet1.Protect Password:="password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, AllowFiltering:=True
    End If
Xit:
End Sub
```

This is based on a common piece of code found on multiple forums which seems to work for everyone else. This code USED to work and then something broke it. I thought it was the `Range` being wrong (which I fixed) but that didn't solve the problem.

## What I've tried:

- Running the separate code lines in the Immediate window - everything runs properly
- Stepping through the code with F8 and `debug.print` to check what is being pulled by `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address` - this pulls the entire input range every time, regardless of what is in the cells but pulls the correct range when run in the Immediate window

  - Stepping through also produces no errors and shows that every `if` and `with` statement is working correctly
- Running the code from different locations (`Sheet1`, `Module`, `ThisWorkbook`) including separating into multiple subs across different locations - no change
- Running the code on a brand-new test workbook with no other macros - still doesn't work
- Different methods for locking the cells such as a loop through all cells in the range instead of using `SpecialCells` - didn't work

Even the `Protect`/`Unprotect` lines are not working which leads me to believe that the code is somehow disconnected from the worksheet itself.

Anyone have any ideas how that is possible? Or how to fix it?

Comment: The code is an event handler, so in order to make it run when the workbook is saved, it needs to go be in the ThisWorkbook class module. A general recommendation is to put `Option Explicit` at the top of the code to catch any variables that are not correctly declared.

Comment: Where is `bRangeEdited` declared (as a Global?) and how is its value set?  Your code only sets it to False.

Comment: Works fine for me if I comment out anything to do with `bRangeEdited`

Comment: @OlleSjögren I tried placing it in ThisWorkbook and using Option Explicit. This didn't work.

Comment: @TimWilliams bRangeEdited is a global variable that gets set to true when something in the worksheet is edited. This tells the macro to lock those cells.
I ended up getting it to work by placing the sub within the worksheet being edited and calling the sub from the Workbook_BeforeClose() event. It's not as elegant but for some reason, the Workbook_BeforeSave() event handler just wasn't working for me.